# Angular extending Interface conditionally

Tags: angular, typescript, interface

I have the below interface structure

```
export interface Details {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    sex: string;
  }

  export interface PersonalDetails extends Details {
salary: number;
  }
```

when I call it in my component something like

```
  public params: Details = <Details>{};
```

if I get a certain user which I am checking in ngOnInit() I want the params to be an instance of PersonalDetails not Details.

How can I change the initiation of the params to point to PersonalDetails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interfaces are mainly frames for specific types bundled in an object and you don't initialize them like a class, as they have no constructor. However, you can create an object by declaring the same structure as your interface, such as:

```js
personalDetails: PersonalDetails = {name: 'Bob', age: 32, sex: 'Male', salary: 450000}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach, which makes use of function overloading:

```js
function getActualParams(params: PersonalDetails): PersonalDetails
function getActualParams(params: Details): Details
function getActualParams(params: PersonalDetails | Details): PersonalDetails | Details {
  if ('salary' in params) {
    return params as PersonalDetails;
  }

  return params;
}

const o1: Details = { name: 'a', age: 18, sex: 'M' };
const r1 = getActualParams(o1); // Details

const o2: PersonalDetails = { name: 'a', age: 18, sex: 'M', salary: 12 }
const r2 = getActualParams(o2);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=26&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgEWBkwQBsBnOAbwCg564lMBbYALjnJimQHMBuOg0y92jAK7MARmkENOoDlx5IBQgL40hoSLEQo0WXHAAKachCalCxMpVCokAE0o2SFakPrlMpTFABPDiRJGSg5OE0adHEkbBgESzhRGABBePFfE38WcgAKMBzmcg4zKAsrNzsASlLzS18qimjY%20MSkZKJ0mEzSbKhcgqKSgiJ3clrR22aYuISklO7e-sHCgeK68obrMbs4AB8p8cmyisbdj0Omylp6BHQ4PIByHz9Ap-04Ndzqz3koIjiKAdb7FOCYSinbbXCJRegAnrAr7DQRRbCWLhwCAARg41zgAF5qIwWGInpgngAacGiDjYgAc1PIijgTwAsh91IJ0UhMVBsYTOmkMllhnkcdV%20HAAPTSo52LQ8zEQABMmzOO2mlCJVBJrA45KpNLEDKZLPZRte-iCcGxKsiNCV8Cg9qJixFfTFqslNCAA)